# GetDOMElementById vs GetElementById

Tags: javascript

I've found this GetDOMElementById function in an old project and apparently is creating some problems with IE7. I've tried googling it, of course, but there is almost no documentation; I only know it is related to Gecko somehow.

What is it, and what is the difference from GetElementById?

Thanks!

Comment: never heard about `GetDOMElementById`. Don't use it, even if that was implemented in some crazy outlaw browser(version).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Search your code base for `GetDOMElementById`. It must be a "custom" function that somebody at your company wrote. It isn't part of the browser API (at least it's not a standard DOM function).

Comment: You were right ¬¬ the fact that it appears in apparently-mozilla-related documentation, and a workmate that was supposed to know that, mislead me. Thanks.